# Where does the phrase 'Crazy as a Coconut' originate from?

Tags: phrase-origin

I recently overheard someone referring to another person as being 'Crazy as a coconut'. I hadn't heard this phrase before so later on I started researching. My initial thought was that he had made up himself as I didn't find many results. I did however see this phrase used as lyrics in a song by a band called 'The Avalanches' titled 'Frontier Psychiatrist'. 
I see someone else had raised question on Answers.com and received an obscene response but hoping someone here might provide a more helpful response as to its origination.

Comment: Understand that "crazy as a X" is a common expression, with many different objects being used for X.  It's often ad-hoc.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase is “***crazy in the coconut”***:

> Popularized by the Australian electronic music group The Avalanches in their song "[Frontier Psychiatrist](https://www.google.com/search?q=crazy%20in%20the%20coconut&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&oq=crazy%20in%20the%20coconut%20&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0l2j69i60l2.5482j0j7&hl=it&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)".
>
> - *Lie down on the couch, what does that mean?*
> - *You're a nut! You're crazy in the coconut!*
> - *What does that mean? That boy needs therapy*

It refers to the slang meaning of coconut as ***[head](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/pich45i)*** whose usage dates back to the first part of the 19th century.

> 1848 -    Bell’s Life in Sydney 30 Dec. 2/6: *Kenny shook his cocoa nut like a mandarin in a Ludgate Hill Grocer’s.*

(GDoS)

Answer (score -1):

When the coconut was brought back from the tropics people found it so strange milk from a nut strange delicious pulp found up a tall tall tree SO STRANGE & CRAZY!!!! so crazier than a coconut.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).